# How to calculate t distribution in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, statistics

Is there a library or easy way to calculate a t distribution in Objective-C? I have a null hypothesis about the mean of a sample set, and I'm able to calculate the average, standard deviation, standard error, and test statistic as follows:

```
// Calculate average
NSExpression *averageExpression = [NSExpression expressionForFunction:@"average:" arguments:@[[NSExpression expressionForConstantValue:data]]];
NSNumber *average = [averageExpression expressionValueWithObject:nil context:nil];

// Calculate StandardDeviation
NSExpression *stdDevExpression = [NSExpression expressionForFunction:@"stddev:" arguments:@[[NSExpression expressionForConstantValue:data]]];
NSNumber *stddev = [stdDevExpression expressionValueWithObject:nil context:nil];

// Calculate StandardError
double std_err = ([stddev doubleValue]/(sqrt(sampleSize - 1)));

// Calculate Test Statistic
double test = ([average doubleValue] - hyothesis) / std_err;

// TODO: Calculate t-dist
```

Now I need to calculate the t distribution for that test statistic, sampleSize - 1 degrees of freedom, and with one tail. In google sheets I just use =tdist(stat, n - 1, 1).

What's the appropriate way to do this calculation in Objective-C? Are there functions that provide me this information in a similar way or do I need to write them on my own?

Comment: What's the formula of "tdist"? I guess that there should be one, no?

Comment: Yes, but I'm more interested in understanding what is out there to solve this problem. I feel like I can't be the first person to need a tdist in iOS. For example, I know that the GNU Scientific Library supports the function in C, but all of the distributions to OS X are x86, i.e. I can't link them on iOS

Answer (score 0):

I was able to implement [this code](http://www.mymathlib.com/functions/probability/students_t_distribution.html) and wrap it in an objective c function as follows in my own `Statistics` class:

```
+ (NSNumber * _Nullable)tdist:(double)x nu:(int)nu {
    if (x < 0) {
        return nil;
    }
    if (nu < 1) {
        return nil;
    }
    return @(Student_t_Distribution(x, nu));
}
```

I unit tested the function with test cases similar to the following, basing my answer off of a google spreadsheet using `=tdist(x, nu, 1)` and with .0000000001 accuracy, and it happily returned the correct answer.

```
- (void)testValidValue {
    double x = 9.025217197;
    int nu = 7;
    double answer = 0.00002094378853;
    XCTAssertEqualWithAccuracy(1.0 - [[Statistics tdist:x nu:nu] doubleValue], answer, .0000000001, @"Failed calculation");
}
```